# Hibernate Fetch Profiles with JPA Repositories

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am working with Hibernate and JPA repositories and i wonder why I can't set up FetchProfiles and use them with a repository like this:

```
entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).enableFetchProfile("example");
repository.findAll()
```

The first line does not have any effect to the second.
Instead I need to get my data via criteria query(like in the docs):

```
List<EntityA> entities = session.createCriteria(EntityA.class)
            .list();
```

Is there any possibility to use fetch profiles together with JPA repositories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Hibernate Fetch Profiles` aren't supported in JPA 2.1, you should use `JPA Entity Graphs` instead. Here is a good starting [tutorial](http://www.radcortez.com/jpa-entity-graphs/).