# Hibernate @FetchProfile with FetchMode.SUBSELECT alternative in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am looking for way to enable/disable FetchMode.SUBSELECT for different queries in JPA.
According to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36911454/5810648

I have to use JPA entity graph instead. Is there any way to achieve behavior similar to Hibernate FetchMode.SUBSELECT using JPA?